# SetPixelFormat возвращает 0, но только в релизе

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl

Пытаюсь создать контекст для OpenGL, в debug работает отлично но в release функция SetPixelFormat возвращет 0, GetLastError тоже.

Может кто знает в чем проблема?

```
HRESULT engine::render::InitContext(HWND _hWnd, engine::math::vec2 _glVersion) {

    WNDCLASSA temporary_class = { 0 };
    temporary_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    temporary_class.lpfnWndProc = DefWindowProcA;
    temporary_class.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(0);
    temporary_class.lpszClassName = "kjadgflkashdglh22";

    RegisterClassA(&temporary_class);

    HWND temporary_window = CreateWindowExA(
        0,
        temporary_class.lpszClassName,
        "openGLConetextTemporary",
        0,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        0,
        0,
        temporary_class.hInstance,
        0);

    HDC temporary_dc = GetDC(temporary_window);

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { 0 };

    pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    pfd.nVersion = 1;
    pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    pfd.cColorBits = 32;
    pfd.cColorBits = 24;
    pfd.cAlphaBits = 8;

    int pixel_format = ChoosePixelFormat(temporary_dc, &pfd);

    SetPixelFormat(temporary_dc, pixel_format, &pfd);

    HGLRC temporary_context = wglCreateContext(temporary_dc);

    if (!wglMakeCurrent(temporary_dc, temporary_context)) engine::FatalError(L"Error create temporary context");

    wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (wglCreateContextAttribsARB_type*)wglGetProcAddress(
        "wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
    wglChoosePixelFormatARB = (wglChoosePixelFormatARB_type*)wglGetProcAddress(
        "wglChoosePixelFormatARB");

    wglMakeCurrent(temporary_dc, 0);
    wglDeleteContext(temporary_context);
    ReleaseDC(temporary_window, temporary_dc);
    DestroyWindow(temporary_window);
    UnregisterClassA("kjadgflkashdglh22", GetModuleHandle(0));

    int pixel_format_attribs[] = {
    WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB,     GL_TRUE,
    WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB,     GL_TRUE,
    WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB,      GL_TRUE,
    WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB,       WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB,
    WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB,         WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
    WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB,         32,
    WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB,         24,
    WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB,       8,
    0
    };

    HDC real_dc = GetDC(_hWnd);

    int pixel_format2;
    UINT num_formats;
    wglChoosePixelFormatARB(real_dc, pixel_format_attribs, 0, 1, &pixel_format2, &num_formats);
    if (!num_formats) {
        engine::FatalError(L"Error choose pixel format");
    }

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd2 = { 0 };
    DescribePixelFormat(real_dc, pixel_format2, sizeof(pfd2), &pfd2);
    int err = SetPixelFormat(real_dc, pixel_format2, &pfd2);
    if (!err) {
        engine::Message(L"Error set pixel format");
        engine::FatalError(std::to_string(GetLastError()).c_str());
    }

    int gl33_attribs[] = {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, _glVersion.x,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, _glVersion.y,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0,
    };

    HGLRC gl33_context = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(real_dc, 0, gl33_attribs);
    if (!gl33_context) {
        engine::FatalError(L"Error create context");
    }

    if (!wglMakeCurrent(real_dc, gl33_context)) {
        engine::FatalError(L"Error make context");
    }

    UpdateWindow(_hWnd);

    return (gladLoadGL()) ? S_OK : -1;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

РЕШЕНИЕ:
В релизе нельзя создать контекст в отдельном потоке, отдельном от того где был зарегистрирован класс, создано окно, и запущен цикл сообщений. А использовать функции ГЛ можно только из потока который создал контест.

ВОПРОС:
Может можно как-то рисовать не в одном потоке с PeekMessage?

Comment: Не используйте ответы для новых вопросов. Если есть новый вопрос - задавайте его отдельно